# Should I change parallelism (MaxDop and Threshold)?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, parallelism, maxdop

Seems like I have problems with parallelism because largest wait types are `CXCONSUMER` and `CXPACKET`.

Server has 8 cores.
So I am planning to bump up
Cost Threshold to **50** and
MaxDop to **4**

Currently I have default values, which is

- 5 - cost threshold for parallelism
- 0 - max degree of parallelism

[image]

Mostly, only a couple of databases are used intensively out of all databases we have on instance. Which makes me wonder whether I should implement those changes on a whole instance or only on a couple of databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2017 or above you can enable query store on databases and see the wait stats for each one of the databases so you can decide if you can set maxdop at database scope or at instance scope.